# Better way to make a "bullet" for a game in c++?

Tags: c++, logic

So, i'm making a game in c++. However, while creating a "bullet" i havent seen any way to make it go upwards without using a for loop. That makes the whole game sleep while the bullet goes up, have any of you got any better idea as how to make this work without denying any player movement?
actual code (absolutely disgustanh, improving the bulletpos and enemypos check soon, i < 6 is because the enemy is at y:5 and player at y:10):

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    if (bullet.Y == enemy.pos.Y && bullet.X == enemy.pos.X || bullet.Y  == enemy1.pos.Y && bullet.X == enemy1.pos.X + 2|| bullet.Y == enemy1.pos.Y && bullet.X == enemy1.pos.X + 1 || bullet.Y == enemy1.pos.Y && bullet.X == enemy1.pos.X + 3 || bullet.Y == enemy1.pos.Y && bullet.X == enemy.pos.X + 4 ){
        enemy1.sprite = "+10";
        score += 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Maybe try to clear up what you want to say.

Answer (score 0):

What framework are you using? Does it have timer-events?

Then add a timer events for things that needs to be done in regular interval, like moving a "bullet" (or just about any other animation that needs to happen in the background).

Each timer event you update the bullet position and redraw it, until it reaches its destination (or other hit-box to make it disappear).

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i want.